# Bogus TimeoutException reading .NETCF SerialPort

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, serial-communication

EDIT: Was a hardware problem.....getting a duplicate device or cable seemed to solve the problem.

Hello, I am pulling my hair out trying to read a large quantity of data (~1MB) from a serial port in .NETCF.

I'm reading a dump of GPS data, but I am randomly receiving a TimeoutException on the call to m_serial.Read(..)

There is definitely data streaming in on the serial port -- the dump takes a couple minutes.  When I get the timeout, I can just plug the serial cable into a different computer and see the data streaming steadily by.

I've tried implementing this several different ways -- SerialPort.Read, SerialPort.ReadLine, SerialPort.ReadExisting -- and they all will read for a short time (random amount) and then fail with a TimeoutException.

Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you!  I'm basically at a loss as how I'm getting a timeout when there is certainly data available, streaming at 38400 baud

```
//m_serial is a SerialPort object, ReadTimeout set to 9000

                    string eoftest = "\r\n$PSRF206";
                    byte[] bEOFTest = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(eoftest);

                    int bufferSize = 1024 * 16;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                    int testingIndex = 0;

                    while (testingIndex < bEOFTest.Length)
                    {
                        int count = m_serial.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                        if (count > 0)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                            {
                                if (buffer[i] == bEOFTest[testingIndex])
                                {
                                    testingIndex++;
                                    if (testingIndex >= bEOFTest.Length)
                                        break;
                                }
                                else
                                    testingIndex = 0;
                            }

                            writer.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                        }
                  }
```

UPDATE:

I've discovered that the code runs fine on a Motorola Symbol device, but not on an intermec device that I have.  I've swapped out all the hardware to try and eliminate that as a possibility, and it still doesn't work.

Both devices are Windows Mobile 5.0

Comment: Any reason you can't use the GPS Intermediate Driver so you don't have to do this low level stuff?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms850332.aspx

Comment: As best as I can tell, that API is just for getting current values.  Our device is disconnected for a work day, then this code runs to get a data dump.  I'm not seeing that functionality in that link, although maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Nope, it's just for getting current values.  I didn't know how much of a dump you were getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just great....looks like it was a hardware problem....I got some other devices available now and it's working fine.....

Answer (score 0):

As a suggestion you could always try using the [OpenNETCF serial port library](http://opennetcf.com/FreeSoftware/OpenNETCFIOSerial/tabid/252/Default.aspx).  It's interface compatible and that way you have all of the source down to the device manager calls, so you can see why any errors might be thrown.